# Wordpress isset( $_POST['submit'] in post query

Tags: php, wordpress

When i add some value in wordpress query ( an archive page )  one value for one post --- all post get some meta

i want add value to one post
[its my problem - value update on other posts ( image is here  )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R8dS.png)

my code is here

```
<?php   if ( $query->have_posts() ):   ?>
 <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
 
 
 
<!-- add from & button is here-->
<form method="post" action="" >
  <button type='submit' name='add-value' value="add">add </button>
</form>              

  
<!-- form update is here -->
<?php if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){
  echo 'update text';
} else  if ( ! empty( $_POST['add-value'] ) ) {
update_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'bookmark', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['add-value'] ) );
} ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
<?php endif;   ?>
```

when meta update for one post , all posts update to some meta

Comment: if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) 
What is the reason of using $_POST['submit'] ? It will never set since there is no field named "Submit"

Comment: thanks for help <3 , but problem isn't it, when meta update for one post , all posts update to some meta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have slightly changed your code. Hopefully, it may help, let me know if any issue.

```
<?php   if ( $query->have_posts() ):   ?>
 <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
 
 
 
<!-- add from & button is here-->
<form method="post" action="" >
  <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
  <button type='submit' name='add-value' value="add">add </button>
</form>              

  
<!-- form update is here -->
<?php if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){
  echo 'update text';
} else  if ( ! empty( $_POST['add-value'] ) ) {
update_post_meta( $_POST['post_id'], 'bookmark', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['add-value'] ) );
} ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
<?php endif;   ?>
```

It should update the exact post meta

Comment: thanks alot  you are amazing <3 its perfect - working